# Why always undefined variable? I was already compact

Tags: php, laravel

> ErrorException thrown with message "Undefined variable: categories
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MimiShop\resources\views\managecategory.blade.php)"

---

view

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr scope="row" id="categoryName">
        <td><option value="{{$category->categoryid}}">{{$category->name}}/option></td>
        <td><a href="/updatecategory/{{$category->categoryid}}"> <button>Edit</button></a></td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

---

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $categories=category::all();
    return view('managecategory', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Maybe post your controller and view code so we could possibly see what is happening.

Comment: Show your code, your controller, and the view blade. These Errors you're posting help with nothing

Comment: Don't need your stacktrace codes..You should post your controller and view codes

Comment: Its far more helpful if you can post your actual code rather than the error message as its generally difficult to identify the problem with the error message along. It could be a simple naming mistake, indexing error, or a number of other things.

Comment: need anything else ?

Comment: Post the code *as text*, not as links to screenshots. But looking at it, is the template related in any way to your `index` method…?

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Your model is probably named `Category` but you're using it as a `category` (lower case). Also, make sure you import the class at the top of your controller correctly.

Comment: i created the model name  as category

Comment: You should create model with uppercase first letter..like ```Category```

Comment: yeah, i know it after i created. but now can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you certain you're hitting the route calling this method `index()` ? Not a different method that also returns the view `managecategory` ?

Comment: Your code looks good this should work. So it could be that your route is using an another function or controller which also returns the `managecategory` view or somewhere in your view your are reseting the `categories` variable (or something like this). So eventually try to rename `categories` to something other.

Comment: Try return $categories after ```$categories=category::all()```  in your controller. What it returns? @ElvinPatraleo